# Difference between two similar pieces of Classic ASP code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

A page I'm working on uses some ASP to download a file. Depending on some condition, it will use one of two ASP files. There is only one small difference between the files.

The first one:

```
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1
```

And the second:

```
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.Open
```

What is the difference between these two? I wouldn't think that setting the stream's type before or after opening it would really matter.

Answer (score 3):

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>
> The **Type** property is read/write only when the current position is at
>   the beginning of the Stream (Position is 0), and read-only at any
>   other position.

So, if you can change it you can change it. It does not matter changing it after or before the invoking  `Open` method.

Comment: It would still be at position 0 after opening though wouldn't it? And keep in mind that both versions of code are being used. In fact, the one that sets the type after opening is used more often that the one that doesn't.

Comment: @JamesPaterson yes it would. An empty stream's position is always 0, and you only can change the type when the position is 0.

Comment: So in other words, both pieces of code do the exact same thing?